# How to auto populate a form textarea with the URL of the page it resides on?

Tags: jquery, forms, url, textarea

I have a 'send to friend' form on a client's web site. The form works great
except for one thing - I can't get the URL of the current page to auto-populate
in the textarea on the form.

http://www.litigationbusters.com/expert-witness.shtml

If you scroll down to the bottom, in the lighter blue bar is a 'Send' link. Click
it and the form will appear.

I am hoping to be able to do this using jQuery or something else equally platform
independent, since the site is on a Windows server for now, but may be moving to
a Linux server in the near future.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the URL of the current page with jQuery, you can use

```
$(location).attr('href')
```

or to simply read the current URL without jQuery, you can use

```
document.URL
```

To populate the textarea with that value when the page loads

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var message = 'check out ' + document.URL;
    $('#message').text(message);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting the `<textarea />` auto-populated on load can be accomplished *without* the use of jQuery.

Say if you have the following HTML:

```
<textarea id="my-textarea"></textarea>
```

With vanilla JavaScript, all you have to do is put the following JavaScript somewhere it can be executed after the `document` is ready:

```
document.getElementById('my-textarea').innerHTML = window.location;
```

You can find a simple example [here](http://jsbin.com/ojemif/2/edit).